# How JEE6 makes the link between Observer and Observee (Observer Pattern)

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1

I've read some blog articles about Observer pattern implementation on JEE6 and something bother me... I can't find any information atm so i ask there...

I've found the following exemples:

```
@Stateless
[...]
public class ParisJugService {

   @Inject
   Event event;

   public void helloParis(){
        System.out.println("Hello Paris");
        event.fire("hello Paris invoked!");
   }
}

@Stateless
public class EventReceiver {

    public void onHelloParis(@Observes String message){
        System.out.println("----------- " + message);
    }
}
```

And

```
public class MyEvent {
    String data;
    Date eventTime;
    ....

}

public class EventProducer {

  @Inject @Any Event<MyEvent> event;


  public void doSomething() {
       MyEvent e=new MyEvent();
      e.data="This is a test event";
      e.eventTime=new Date();
      event.fire(e);

  }

}


public class EventConsumer {


    public void afterMyEvent(@Observes MyEvent event) {

        // .. Insert event logic here
    }

}
```

I can't understand how the link between event consumer and event producer is done...

Is it by naming convention of the methods? (Where the words "on", "after", "before"... will have sense)

Is it by comparison of given arguments (here String and MyEvent)?

I can't know and don't see what else could it be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link between the event firing and the listener is based on the event type.

In your example:

```
public class EventConsumer {

    public void afterMyEvent(@Observes MyEvent event) {
        // .. Insert event logic here
    }

}
```

This class will receive all fired events of type MyEvent, wherever they come from.

Source: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/event/Observes.html

Comment: Is the signature of onHelloParis in the example in the question actually correct?

Comment: First answer posted accepted :)

So in these exemples, i wonder what the "onXXX" and "afterXXX" means... nothing?

Comment: i guess the signature is correct yes. 
This exemple was given by Adam Bien

Comment: It takes a String, how can it be connected to the approriate event?

Comment: @Sebastien Lorber note that the order of showing answers is random, not chronological.

Comment: tkr actually it seems all observers with a String attribute signature will be triggered i think, including onHelloParis.
Bozho i know but i used a DateComparator() :)

Answer (score 6):

The container keeps metadata about all beans inside it. On startup it registers all observer methods together with the *event type* (the `Class` of the argument) they observe. Whenever an event is fired, the list of observers is checked for methods that accept the appropriate type of event.

Comment: @Sebastien Lorber what do you mean by "to late" ?? My answer was given 5 minutes after you asked the question, and 2 minutes before the accepted answer.

Comment: Is the signature of onHelloParis in the example in the question actually correct?

It takes a String, how can it be connected to the approriate event?

Comment: perhaps i'm wrong but anyway you already have enough points :p